# Join table in a row sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT TBL1.C1, TBL1.C2, TBL2.C3, TBL2.C4 
    FROM(
        SELECT 100 C1, 'ABC' C2
        UNION
        SELECT 101 C1, 'XYZ' C2
        UNION 
        SELECT 102 C1, 'PQR' C2 
        UNION
        SELECT 103 C1, 'MNO' C2
        ) TBL1,
        (
        SELECT 1 C3, 'Saving Deposits' C4
        UNION
        SELECT 2 C3, 'Current Deposits' C4
        UNION
        SELECT 3 C3, 'Term Deposits' C4
        )TBL2
```

Above query is giving following result

```
--------------------------------------------
C1  |  C2 |C3 |     C4
--------------------------------------------
100 | ABC | 1 | Saving Deposits
101 | XYZ | 1 | Saving Deposits
100 | ABC | 2 | Current Deposits
101 | XYZ | 2 | Current Deposits
100 | ABC | 3 | Term Deposits
101 | XYZ | 3 | Term Deposits
```

but i am expecting result like below

```
--------------------------------------------
C1  |  C2 |C3 |     C4
--------------------------------------------
100 | ABC | 1 |  Saving Deposits
100 | ABC | 2 | Current Deposits
100 | ABC | 3 | Term Deposits
101 | XYZ | 1 | Saving Deposits
101 | XYZ | 2 | Current Deposits
101 | XYZ | 3 | Term Deposits
```

Please help me ....

Comment: ... Did you consider using an order-by clause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `ORDER BY` at the end of your query:

```
ORDER BY TBL1.C1, TBL1.C2, TBL2.C3
```

So your whole query should be:

```
SELECT TBL1.C1, TBL1.C2, TBL2.C3, TBL2.C4 
    FROM(
        SELECT 100 C1, 'ABC' C2
        UNION
        SELECT 101 C1, 'XYZ' C2
        UNION 
        SELECT 102 C1, 'PQR' C2 
        UNION
        SELECT 103 C1, 'MNO' C2
        ) TBL1,
        (
        SELECT 1 C3, 'Saving Deposits' C4
        UNION
        SELECT 2 C3, 'Current Deposits' C4
        UNION
        SELECT 3 C3, 'Term Deposits' C4
        )TBL2
    ORDER BY TBL1.C1, TBL1.C2, TBL2.C3
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
SELECT TBL1.C1, TBL1.C2, TBL2.C3, TBL2.C4 
    FROM(
        SELECT 100 C1, 'ABC' C2
        UNION
        SELECT 101 C1, 'XYZ' C2
        UNION 
        SELECT 102 C1, 'PQR' C2 
        UNION
        SELECT 103 C1, 'MNO' C2
        ) TBL1,
        (
        SELECT 1 C3, 'Saving Deposits' C4
        UNION
        SELECT 2 C3, 'Current Deposits' C4
        UNION
        SELECT 3 C3, 'Term Deposits' C4
        )TBL2 
Order by TBL1.C2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Order by to order the output primarily by c2 in ascending order and secondarily c3 in ascending order.